# Медленная работа с БД через PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, dao, preparedstatement

Как мне в этом коде, сделать так, чтобы я верно использовал `PrepareStatement`? 
Я уже всю реализацию ДАО не скидываю, так как очень много кода. В моем коде `PrepareStatement` замедляет работу, а нужно чтобы ускорял. Я его использую не верно. Я так понимаю, мне его как то открыть надо один раз, потом использовать везде как-то, и потом закрыть? Буду рад любой помощи.

```
public class MySqlDaoStudent implements DaoStudent {
    private PreparedStatement stm=null;

    private final Connection connection;

    private ResultSet rs=null;

    public MySqlDaoStudent(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public Student read(int key) throws SQLException {
        String sql="SELECT * FROM student_db.student where id = ?;";
        Student student = new Student();
        try {
            stm = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            stm.setInt(1, key);
            rs = stm.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            student.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
            student.setFirst_name(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
            student.setSecond_name(rs.getString("SECOND_NAME"));
         } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(rs!=null){
                rs.close();
            } 
            if(connection!=null){
                connection.close();
            }
            if (stm!=null){
                stm.close();
            }
        }
        return student;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> getAll() throws SQLException {
        String sql="SELECT * FROM student_db.student";
        List<Student> list=new ArrayList<>();
        Student student=new Student();
        try{
            stm=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=stm.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                student.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
                student.setFirst_name(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
                student.setSecond_name(rs.getString("SECOND_NAME"));
                list.add(student);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(rs!=null){
                rs.close();
            }
            if(connection!=null){
                connection.close();
            }
            if (stm!=null){
                stm.close();
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: скорее всего проблема в том, что соединение постоянно закрываешь и открываешь. еще попробуй этот вариант `Statement statement = getConnection().createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);`

Comment: спасибо за ответ.. да согласен statement быстрее будет , я даже проверил уже методом System.currentTimeMillis(), посчитал время. но у меня задача, использовать именно PS. И как я понял, что нужно один раз открыть PS использовать его сколько надо, а потом закрыть.

Comment: тогда не закрывай `connection.close();`

Comment: я уже боюсь , что то отправлять )) ибо ошибки у меня больше не может быть ) а где его закрывать тогда ? в конце самого последнего метода ?  вообще на практике , как это выглядит ?

Comment: вот например этот кусок кода :

Comment: что отправлять? заметил,что в методе `getAll` ты в лист добавляешь ссылку на один и тот же элемент. нужно будет инициализировать student внутри цикла

Comment: ок. понял. спасибо.

Comment: закрывать нужно в отдельном методе. которая будет вызвана в нужный момент

Comment: @SeniorAutomator как тут код еще вставить ? не в коммент же его

Comment: т.е. у меня есть : 
PreparedStatement pstm=null;
pstm=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
 rs=pstm.executeQuery();

и таких у меня 7 методов , которые используют PS.

а потом нужен метод закрытия PS ?

Comment: как такой метод выглядит ? вы меня сильно выручите .

Comment: я предлагаю вот [такой](http://ideone.com/inV83d)  вариант. пробуй и посмотри сколько времени займет

Comment: спасибо всем огромное !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верное использование PreparedStatement заключается в том, что необходимо подготовить запрос в СУБД, прежде, чем он будет отправлен. Его нужно подготовить, сохранить в поле, а потом использовать, таким образом достигается максимальная скорость обработки любых запросов в любом кол-ве. Вот код решения моего вопроса: 
(sql запрос сохранил в константу)

```
  /*   Константа sql запроса */
  private static final String SQL_SELECT_ALL_STUDENT = 
  "SELECT id, first_name, second_name FROM student_db.student";

  /* поле подключения */
  private Connection connection = null;
  /* поле PS */
  private PreparedStatement psSelectAllStudent = null;

 // использую Properties для чтения user,password,driver,url
 // подключаюсь к СУБД
  private Connection getConnection() throws DaoException {
  Properties property = new Properties();
  InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
       inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
        property.load(inputStream);
        String url = property.getProperty("url");
        String user = property.getProperty("user");
        String password = property.getProperty("password");
        String driver = property.getProperty("driver");
        Class.forName(driver);
        if (connection == null) {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        DaoException er = new DaoException("ошибка загрузки файла ", ex);
        throw er;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        DaoException er = new DaoException("ошибка Class.forName(driver) ", ex);
        throw er;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        DaoException er = new DaoException("ошибка соединения с СУБД ", ex);
        throw er;
    }
    return connection;
}


  //подготавливаю PS в СУБД и сохраняю в поле

    private void selectAllStudentPs(String sql) throws DaoException {
    getConnection();
    try {
        if (psSelectAllStudent == null) {
            psSelectAllStudent = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        }
    } catch (SQLException er) {
        DaoException ex = new DaoException("ошибка подготовки запроса в selectStudentPs ", er);
        throw ex;
    }
}

  //получаю список того, что было необходимо сделать в задании 
   @Override
    public List<Student> selectAllStudent() throws DaoException {
    ResultSet resultSet=null;
    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        selectAllStudentPs(SQL_SELECT_ALL_STUDENT);
        resultSet = psSelectAllStudent.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Student ss = new Student();
            ss.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            ss.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
            ss.setSecondName(resultSet.getString("second_name"));
            list.add(ss);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        DaoException er = new DaoException("ошибка выполения SQL_SELECT_ALL_STUDENT ", ex);
        throw er;
    }finally {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                DaoException er = new DaoException("ошибка закрытия resultSet в " +
                        "selectStudent ", ex);
                throw er;
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
    /* ---- */
```

Таким образов и получается именно ускорение PreparedStatement !

Answer (score 2):

Смысл `PreparedStatement` в том, чтобы скомпилировать запрос один раз и использовать все время меняя только параметры запроса. Фактически, компиляция запроса происходит при вызове `PrepareStatement()` - ваша проблема в том, что вы при каждом выполнении запроса заново компилируете запрос.

Отделите мух от котлет, а именно: разделите этап компиляции запроса и этап выполнения прекомпилированного запроса.

Ну и на закуску: поскольку `PreparedStatement` привязан к `Connection`, то при закрытии соединения естественно вы теряете свой прекомплированный запрос (на что вам и указывают в комментариях)

Comment: у меня еще такой вопрос .

Comment: Оформите новый вопрос как положено правилами сайта

Answer (score 1):

рекомендую модернизировать код таким образом

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by TS on 07.02.2017.
 */
public class MySqlDaoStudent implements DaoStudent {
    private static final String ALL_STUDENTS = "SELECT * FROM student_db.student";
    private PreparedStatement stm = null;
    private PreparedStatement allPreparedStatement = null;

    private final Connection connection;

    public MySqlDaoStudent(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    private void init() throws SQLException {
        if (allPreparedStatement == null)
            allPreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(ALL_STUDENTS);

    }

    public Student read(int key) throws SQLException {
        // у нас каждый раз новый key, и так как у нас 1 параметр, запрос легче сформировать так
        String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM student_db.student where id = %s;", key);
        Student student = new Student();
        try (ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql)) { // такая конструкция позволяет закрывать rs (вместо finally) 
            rs.next();
            student.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
            student.setFirst_name(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
            student.setSecond_name(rs.getString("SECOND_NAME"));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return student;
    }

    public List<Student> getAll() throws SQLException {
        init();
        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Student student = new Student();
        try (ResultSet rs = allPreparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                student.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
                student.setFirst_name(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
                student.setSecond_name(rs.getString("SECOND_NAME"));
                list.add(student);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        return list;
    }

    public void closeConnection() throws SQLException {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: у меня еще такой вопрос, у меня в коде есть и удаление и добавление и обновление. как быть с такими запросами ?

Comment: вообще можно ли создать один такой запрос на все сразу ?

Comment: используйте ORM, либо отдельно создавайте

Comment: посмотрите , пожалуйста, вот мой код.. но теперь вопрос, как сделать SQL запрос таким образом, чтоб он работал в каждом методе .. мне нужно соединить в нем две таблицы и брать в каждом методе , те столбцы которые нужны...

Comment: все делаю по справке, и ничего не выходит. не могу создать изолированный блок для вставки кода. что за чудеса такие ?

Comment: я не понял последний вопрос. при возникновении новых вопросов,  
оформите новый вопрос, как положено правилами сайта. а то большая портянка получается